# Better way to write these 2 SQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

It gets the name of the url, finds the ID and use it to find the products associated with this ID.

Is there a better way of writing this? By saying better I mean performance. I do not know if  the two queries can be merged for a better performance.

```
$cname = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["c"]);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM companies WHERE name = '$cname' LIMIT 1"));
$cID = $row['id'];

$products = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM products WHERE company_id = '$cID' " );
while($product = mysql_fetch_assoc($products)) {
                echo $product['name'].'<br>';
            }
```

Comment: Yes, do a simple JOIN.  I can't suggest how though, as you didn't post your table structure.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, get a good book about SQL. It will save you a lot of trouble, and you will get a lot of use from this knowledge.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT c.id, p.name
FROM companies c
INNER JOIN products p ON p.company_id = c.id
WHERE c.name = '$cname'
```

Comment: Join is faster than two queries ?

Comment: It'll save you a whole round-trip to the database from your php code - that'll be the main saving. It ought not make any difference to the database time really. Afterthought: do you have an index on your products table on the companyid? That'd speed up the query too (even in your existing code)

Comment: @BenBrocka Two selects much faster than a JOIN? Are you sure? That's pretty rare in my book (not impossible though). Were your tables indexed correctly?

Comment: Like it has been said, you may see a performance increase in reducing two separate queries down to one.  In many applications, it won't make an appreciable difference (saving a thousandth of a second in a query that runs 100 times an hour isn't much), and in those cases I prefer to keep the code as readable as possible rather than squeeze out that last drop of performance.  Also, remember to set up an index on your "companies" table for the "name" field and your "products" table for the "company_id" field.  Those two indexes will help speed.

Comment: If you think that JOINs are not readable, I weep for your software.

Comment: I think you misread my comment, TehShrike.  I was insinuating that, in this case, based on the asker's circumstances, if it turned out that *not* using joins was a little bit faster that I would use joins anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple join:

```
SELECT p.name FROM products p, companies c
WHERE c.id = p.company_id
AND c.name = '<COMPANY NAME>';
```

As long as the company name is unique then you won't run into any problems.

Answer (score 1):

For security you could (should) consider parameterized queries. See [these results](http://www.google.nl/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=nl&source=hp&q=parameterized+query+mysql&pbx=1&oq=parameterized+query+mysql&aq=f&aqi=g-L1g-vL3&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=21944l22787l1l22955l6l4l0l0l0l0l343l828l0.3.0.1l4l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=1e9e32b33f3f4e&biw=1920&bih=943)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can join them into one:

```
SELECT products.name
  FROM products
  JOIN companies
    ON products.company_id = companies.id
  WHERE companies.name = '$cname'
```

however this loses the LIMIT in the first query - would you ever expect to hit that?

Comment: You need to alias "name" in your SELECT - the field appears to exist in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT p.name
  FROM products p
  JOIN companies c
    ON (p.company_id = c.id)
  WHERE c.name = '$cname'
```